# How to get the dropdown list to go to the default value when the page is refreshed?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a drop down list and the values come from an array. When the user selects an element from the drop down list and clicks submit button it says what element the user selected. Everything works fine, but when I refresh the page, it does not go back to the default element of my drop down list. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

your code that updates the drop down is most likely wrapped with

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{


}
```

which means it will only update the drop down when the page first loads.

move your updating code outside of this clause and see how it works as required.

or at least set the dropdown value to default one outside of this clause. on every `page_load`

Answer (score 0):

Disable the ViewState of your DropDownList with EnableViewState="false".

Comment: If I disable the view state I am getting an error. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button i suppose that you're posting the data somewhere and intercept the click within the click event of the button.When you refresh the page you're forcing a new request to webserver which re-load all data.Are different concept.

Are you binding in code behind your dropdownlist or via sqldatasource or any other datasource?

If you're binding the dropdownlist from code behind you need to intercept if it is a postback or not with the followin statement:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
 //you can bind dropdown here in example
}
else
{//do more stuff here}
```

It depend on your page logic.Let us more details to help you.